# R and Stats: Multiple t-testing

Tags: r

**Because collecting a certain type of data is expensive, 60 labs decided to group up to test the null hypothesis (sample mean is equal to zero) against the alternative (sample mean is not)**. **The 60 labs collect 10 samples each and using an α = 0.05 level, they conduct a hypothesis test on each sample under the assumption that the null hypothesis is true:**

a) Probability that no labs reject the null?

b) Probability that all labs reject the null?

c) Probability that exactly 10 labs reject the null?

---

Because each lab is conducting multiple hypothesis tests (10 each), this leads me to think that false discovery rate or family-wise error rate may be applicable here (not certain). I'm not sure how to obtain the first and third probability, but I believe the second can be obtain by 1 - answer to a. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Is the null hypothesis true?

Comment: Yep! The null is true.

Comment: How do you come up with 600 t-tests? Do you mean each lab conducts ten tests based on each of ten independent samples?  If so, then what does "repeats of the same test" mean, given that these all appear to be based on independent samples--whence there aren't any "repeats" at all? How are the data distributed? (Shall we assume they are truly Normal?)  *Which* of the many t-tests out there is being performed?  (This doesn't matter unless the data might be non-Normal.)

Comment: @whuber Let's presume that the data is normally distributed, and I'm not sure if t-tests even need to be used necessarily. I think I'm making it more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @whuber Also, I think I got confused, there would be 600 samples total, but 60 hypothesis tests.

Comment: I don't think it matters what test you're doing or what assumptions are met. This question seems to focus on the $0.05$ probability and nothing else.

Comment: @Dave It's probably intended that the student focus on the "0.05," but in reality the test and the data type do matter.  Consider, for instance, a t-test based on Binomial data: because of the discreteness of the test statistic, the actual test level is unlikely to equal 0.05--and even a tiny deviation from that value, when multiplied 600 times (or even 60), will noticeably change the calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything is ***exactly as advertised*** (tests are precisely appropriate, the null hypothesis is exactly true, the significance level is exactly 5%, labs work independently, etc.), then the number $X$ of rejections has $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=60, p=.05).$ Using R, the respective answers to (a), (b), and (c) are given below (rounded to five places):

```
round(dbinom(c(0,60,10), 60, .05), 5)
[1] 0.04607 0.00000 0.00057
```

All answers use the binomial PDF. For example, the answers to (a)-(c) can
also be obtained, just using R as a calculator, as follows: $.95^{60}, .05^{50}, {60\choose 10}.05^{10}.95^{50},$ respectively, where ${60\choose 10} = \frac{60!}{10!\cdot 50!} = 75\,394\,027\,566.$

```
.95^60
[1] 0.0460698
05^60
[1] 8.673617e-79
choose(60,10)*.05^10*.95^50
[1] 0.0005665226
```

*Notes:*
(1) I have assumed each lab does five assays and uses the results
to do **one** t test. This makes the specifications such as 'no lab rejects the null` unambiguous. If labs do five tests, each on multiple assays, then you need to clarify how that is done: Same number of assays for each t test? Also, to clarify what 'no lab rejects the null' means: In *none* of its five tests? in *a majority of* its five tests? In *all five* of its tests?

(2) As @whuber has commented, slight variations in
assumptions can make noticeable changes is numerical results
for these probabilities. For example if the significance
level is $0.052$ instead of $0.050,$ we have results below:

```
round(dbinom(c(0,60,10), 60, .052), 5)
[1] 0.04060 0.00000 0.00075
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you for your help!